# Springboot template files are not loaded

Tags: java, templates, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am writing my first springboot web app with project structure like below:

```
---src/main/java
           +com.example.myproject
                                +--Application.java
           +com.example.myproject.domain
                                +--Person.java
           +com.example.myproject.web
                                +--GreetingController.java
---src/main/resources
           +static
                 +--css
                 +--js
           +templates
                 +--greeting.html
```

**Aplication.java**

```
package com.example.myproject;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(false);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

**GreetingController.java**

```
package com.example.myproject.web;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

**greeting.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when i run the project, and type below URL on web browser

```
http://localhost:8080/greeting
```

The result only displays this text:  **greeting**  while it should display this text:  **Hello, World!**

I have tried to move greeting.html out of templates folder but still not lucky. As i understand, springboot should auto scan the components and load resource files correctly.

Please help to advise on this issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Only use `@Controller` annotation, not `@RestController` annotation. It will run fine. `@RestController` contains `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotations. So if you use `@RestController`, you will get a return response from the method it is mapped to.